# Equations associated with an ellipse whose transverse axis is along $Y-$ axis

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, parametric, tangent-line

For an ellipse with a transverse axis along Y-axis. I am writing some of it's associated equations and a parametric point as follows:

Equation for an ellipse $$\frac{x^2}{b^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2}=1\tag{1}$$

Any point on the ellipse $P(\theta)$

$\left(b\cos \theta,a\sin \theta\right)\tag{2}$

Tangent to an ellipse at $P(\theta)$
$$y=mx\pm\sqrt{b^2m^2+a^2}\tag{3}$$

Where $a \gt b$. I want to use $a$ strictly for a major axis.

I know how to use  $(1)$ and $(2)$ together with $y=mx+c$ to get $(3)$.

Is $(2)$ valid?

Comment: Yes, $(2)$ is valid: just substitute it into $(1)$ to check.

Comment: I have checked. It does satisfy $(1)$